# $\pi$, $e$, $\phi$, and sunflowers

Tags: recreational-mathematics, golden-ratio

While reading some internet materials on design, I came across this picture and comment:

[image]

I found it a little bit surprising. I knew that the real sunflower follows golden ratio in some way (but I don't know the details). But how come the patterns for $\pi$ and $e$ are still "periodic", but different? What affects "sparseness" of the pattern? Is there any tool to display the sunflower pattern for different values of the "constant" that generates it?

Are the claims in the picture and in its comment for real at all?

What is the math background beyond all this?

Is the resulting shape different for rational and irrational numbers? What about transcendent numbers?

NOTE: I just saw there is a mistake (most likely a typo) in the picture: $1.681$ should be $1.618$, right?

Comment: Surely it is a biology question how it follows the golden ratio.

Comment: A good reference is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio. See section 3.7 and the references given there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are the patterns for a number $a$ generated? Plot the points with polar coordinates $r=r_0\cdot c^n$, $\theta = \theta_0+n\cdot a\cdot 2\pi$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$, where $c$ is a suitable constant just slightly below $1$ (or above $1$ if wyou want the pattern to grow from inside to outside)

Even though it is not transcendent, $\phi$ is the "most irrational number", and that's what ultimately causes the pattern to be most efficient (and pleasing). 
The statement "most irrational" can be made more precise with the use of continued fractions.
Patterns for rational $a=\frac uv$ would look like a straight "windmill" with $v$ wings. The pattern for $\pi$ looks almost like a straight windmill with $7$ wings. That's from the famous approximation $\pi\approx\frac{22}7$.

Comment: There are not enough turns for the rational/algebraic/transcendent character of these numbers to clearly appear. The "pleasing" aspect of the figure is probably more due to Moiré patterns rather than any "efficiency property". The difference in the effects of the different constants are more due to the curve slope (order of magnitude, first digit of the constant) and density (chosen arbitrarily by the artist to support his claim).

Answer (score 4):

This is pure biomathematical misinformed popularization. These famous constants have no more reason to appear than any other real value, and even if they did, this could be approximately true to the first or second decimal and **unverifiable** for the next.

The pseudo-fitness of $\phi$ as shown on the figure is just due to a smaller value of the constant, resulting in better compactness. And there is no other "periodicity" than that caused by the revolution (actually, there is no periodicity at all, these are spirals).

Besides that, there is a rationale for the golden ratio to appear in nature, due to its relation to the Fibonacci numbers ($F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$): when a physical process involves this recurrence (like in reproduction of rabbits, unlike the pattern of sunflowers), the golden ratio is there in the limit. It also appears with rotational symmetry of order 5 (which, by the way, is known to be impossible as a symmetry order in crystals). Note that any recurrence with integer coefficients can only generate algebraic numbers.

$\pi$ can appear if you roll out the skin of a cylinder of revolution.

I can't think of a simple process that would generate $e$. (Exponential curves arise in many situations in the frame of linear systems, but the basis has no reason to be specifically $e$.)

Last but not least, there is no real relation between aesthetics and the golden ratio, this is folklore. No one would notice a difference between $\phi$ proportions and, say $1.6$ or $\sqrt3$ or $e-1$.

Comment: I assume you've seen Markowsky's [Misconceptions about the Golden Ratio](http://www.umcs.maine.edu/~markov/GoldenRatio.pdf)? He debunks a number of popular beliefs about the golden ratio such as how esthetically pleasing the golden rectangle is, its appearance in the human body, and alleged use in antiquity. The occurrence of the golden ratio in phyllotaxis is *not* addressed. Certainly, one can adjust the golden angle by some small but positive amount and generate similar patterns. But the connection with Fibonacci numbers (which do occur in nature) is real.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Can you explain this connection ?

Comment: The connection between the Fibonacci numbers and the golden ratio that I alluded to? Yes, I can explain that. I suspect that you mean the mysterious occurrence of the golden ratio in nature. My belief is that $\pi$, $e$, and $\phi$ all appear so frequently because they arise in the solutions of simple equations with small, integer coefficients: $y''=-y$, $y'=y$, and $x^2-x-1=0$. You allude to a similar phenomenon with Fibonacci numbers. Not so mysterious. :)

Comment: @MarkMcClure No I allude to your statement that Fibonacci numbers do occur in nature, while you describe no single instance of that. In what specific phenomenon are there Fibonacci numbers (besides the Rabbit population scenario) or the Golden Ratio ?

Comment: I'm not at all under the impression that every plant has a Fibonacci number of leaves or seeds or any such nonsense. As Coxeter said, "We must face the fact that phyllotaxis is really not a universal law but only a fascinatingly prevalent tendency". But even a tendency, along with a reasonable mathematical basis (such as economy of packing), is intriguing.

Comment: In my understanding, Fibonacci-like phyllotaxis needn't have a very accurate ratio.

Answer (score 1):

These kind of patterns comes from biological activities as cell division. The spiral form come from a method of growth and development and the pattern on the curved surface of the base of the composite seems to be the first surface-filling spiral pattern.

The seeds creates in the center and grows bigger as the surface grows wider in a time varying surface filling pattern.

It's masterful geometry.